# What is the hadoop sort comparator class for?

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mapreduce, compare, comparator

I've implementing the hadoop sort comparator class for sorting my key. I know that it use to compare every key. But, I don't know how it can working in detail? Is that true, if it use to compare?

Thanks all....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say, your key is `(Attribute1, Attribute2)`. Now you could use the Sort Comparator, to first sort by Attribute1 and then by Attribute2.

For Example,

```
Key = (2008,32) // year, temperature
```

Now, if you want to sort by year and then by temperature, you could use the Sort Comparator, as follows:

```
public static class KeyComparator extends WritableComparator {
    protected KeyComparator() {
        super(CompositeKey.class, true);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(WritableComparable w1, WritableComparable w2) {
        CompositeKey ip1 = (CompositeKey) w1;
        CompositeKey ip2 = (CompositeKey) w2;
        int result = CompositeKey.compare(ip1.getYear(), ip2.getYear());
        if (result != 0) {
            return result;
        }
        return CompositeKey.compare(ip1.getTemperature(), ip2.getTemperature());
    }
}
```